# Poisson equation estimates near boundary

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

Fix $ \Omega$ a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb R^N$ (take $N$ big) and let $ \frac{N+1}{2}<p<N$.   We now consider nonnegative smooth functions $f$ such that $-\Delta u(x)=f(x) $ in $ \Omega$ with $u=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.  Let $ \delta(x):=\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$ and let's assume we have 
$$ \int_\Omega \frac{f(x)^p}{\delta(x)^{p-1}} dx \le 1.$$    I would like to show there is some $C>0$ (independent of $f$) such that $$\sup_\Omega \frac{u}{\delta} \le C.$$

The usual way I attempt to prove these things is to get a gradient estimate on $u$;  but note since $p<N$ we can't do that.   If I can get any estimates on $u$ near the boundary (say $u$ is small in some $L^1$ sense near the boundary)  then I am able to show the result (but my issue is I am struggling to get any estimates).   If you like you can think of $\Omega$ as a region of the upper half space $\mathbb R^N_+$  with lower boundary $ x_N=0$ and get an estimate on this portion of the boundary.  Any comments would be greatly appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: Am I imagining things or did I see exactly this question on this site before, only a few days ago?

Comment: you did... then two minutes later i thought i knew answer so i deleted it... then another two minutes later i realized i didn't know the answer